# Using the predict() methods of fitted models with gekko

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, predict, gekko

Many model-fitting Python packages have a `predict()` method, which outputs a prediction of the fitted model given observations of the predictor(s).

**Question:** How would I use these `predict()` methods to predict a single value when the observation is a variable in a `gekko` model?

Below is a very simple reproducible example:

***Note:** The actual model that I am fitting is a B-spline using `statsmodels.gam.smooth_basis.BSplines` and `statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.GLMGam`. However, I am hoping that this simple example with `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` will translate to more complex model classes from other packages.*

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# create example data
x = np.arange(100)[:, np.newaxis]
y = np.arange(100) * 2 + 10

plt.plot(x, y)  # plot x vs y data
# plt.show()

model = LinearRegression()  # instantiate linear model
model.fit(x, y)  # fit model

x_predict = np.arange(100, 200)[:, np.newaxis]  # create array of predictor observations
y_predict = model.predict(x_predict)  # use model to make prediction

plt.plot(x_predict, y_predict)  # plot prediction
# plt.show()

m = GEKKO()  # instantiate gekko model

x2 = m.FV()  # instantiate free variable
x2.STATUS = 1  # make variable available for solver

y2 = 50  # true value

# place x2 variable in numpy array to adhere to predict()'s argument requirements
x2_arr = np.array(x2).reshape(1, -1)

# minimize squared error between the true value and the model's prediction
m.Minimize((y2 - model.predict(x2_arr)) ** 2)

m.options.IMODE = 3
# solve for x2
m.solve(disp=True)

print(f"x2 = {x2.value[0]:3f}")
```

I get the following sequential errors:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'GK_FV'`

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

My first thought is that I would have to create a wrapper class around the `gekko.gk_parameter.GK_FV` class to modify the `float()` method, but that's where my knowledge and skills end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gekko ML functions](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ml.html) can import `sklearn`, `gpflow`, and `tensorflow` models. It requires the models to be fit and then the parameters and equations are imported into the `gekko` model.

```py
Gekko_Model = ML.Gekko_LinearRegression(model,Xtrain,RMSE,Gekko_Model)
```

- Import a trained linear regression model from sklearn. This model calculates uncertainty through the delta method for regression methods.
- model: trained model from sklearn as a Ridge Regression or Linear Regression model.
- Xtrain: input training set, needed to calculate the prediction interval.
- RMSE: root mean squared error calculated during training for the entire data set. This is used to calculate the prediction interval.
- Gekko_Model: Gekko model (created by GEKKO()) that is appended with the new Linear Regression model.